# MVC3 Pass bool array of checkbox values to controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

**UPDATE: Turns out I had skipped one checkbox (4) as can be seen from the code. Silly mistake from my side!**

I have 16 checkboxes in my view, and I want each one of them bound to an element in a bool array (or BitArray) in the model.

If I try to do this, after submitting the form the controller only gets the first 4 elements of the array (correct values though), so then I tried to allocate more space in the constructor of the model but then the controller would never even get called. Is there any way I can get this to work, or do I need a bool variable for each checkbox?

The array:

```
public bool[] ActiveSettings { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<p><b>Active Settings:</b></p>
<div style="float:left">
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[0]) val0<br />
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[1]) val1<br />
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[2]) val2<br />
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[3]) val3<br />
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[5]) val4<br />
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[6]) val5<br />
@*etc..*@
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of the debugger in the controller (Should be bool[16]):
[image]

I tested the same thing with an array of integers using Html.EditorFor, and it worked just fine.
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
So what I ended up doing is setting those hidden fields like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[0]) val0<br />
@Html.Hidden("NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[0]",false)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[1]) val1<br />
@Html.Hidden("NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[1]",false)
```

etc...
Here's a weird note though: I have 16 checkboxes, all I had to do was set hidden fields for the first 5, and then magically all 16 of them worked.

Comment: Use a foreach loop. I don't know if it will solve your problem but it's much more elegant.

Comment: You have GOT to be kidding me, that actually solved the problem! Cheers.

Comment: Wow! asp.net mvc really insert hidden bugs if your code is not elegant :)

Comment: Yeah, really weird, this isn't the first time either. Just to clarify, I actually used a for loop, but I'm sure that a foreach would work aswell. I'll go with Jason's solution so I can have labels for my checkboxes, but thanks for the good comment! :)

Comment: taking a look at your code snippet above... you are missing `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NetworkSettings.ActiveSettings[4]) val0<br />`. that's why it's failing. Checkboxfor automatically creates the checkbox and hidden field for you.

Comment: I don't know whether I should laugh or cry right now... I facepalmed so hard you have no idea. I actually noticed and fixed it while doing the hidden values but kept on going thinking it wasn't the cause. Thanks, and sorry everyone for the waste of time, should I leave the question up? Wouldn't want you to lose those reputation points!

Comment: keep it around, someone else may run into the same thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the rendered html for `Checkboxfor`? and is the 5th check box unchecked? a checkbox is only submitted in the form collection if the value is true. if the value is false it's just not sent. MS MVC requires a non-breaking zero-based index of values for an array.

So if options 1-4 are checked, option 5 is unchecked and options 6-16 are checked only 1-4 hydrated into the view model. 5 is not part of the forms collection and 6-16 are ignored.

to resolve this a hidden field with the same name as the checkbox needs to be submitted as well. the hidden field has a value of false.  The modelbinder will use the checkbox value first. if it's not present the default value of `false` was submitted and will be used.  the markup looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="networksettings_activesettings_4" name="networksettings.activesettings[4]" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" id="networksettings_activesettings_4_hidden" name="networksettings.activesettings[4]" value="false" />
```

Comment: Setting the hidden fields worked, and thanks for the explanation!